# EF core retrieve a navigation property for a single entry in a single DB trip without joining before filtering

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I was trying to find a way with EF core to get an entry and it's navigation property without joining the whole tables then filtering so for example, let' say we have these two classes

```cs
public partial class Instructor
{
    public int InsId { get; set; }

    public string InsName { get; set; }

    public int? DeptId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Dept { get; set; }
}
```

now let's say I want to get the Instructor with Id = 2 and his department.

I tried the following queries and saw their output in SQL profiler:

```cs
//joins whole tables first
context.Instructors.Include(i => i.Dept).FirstOrDefault(i => i.InsId == 2);

//joins whole tables first
context.Instructors.Where(i => i.InsId == 2).Select(i => new
{
    i.InsName,
    i.Salary,
    i.Dept
}).FirstOrDefault();

//joins whole tables first
var result = context.Instructors
    .Where(i => i.InsId == 2)
    .Join(context.Departments,
        i => i.DeptId,
        d => d.DeptId,
        (i, d) => new { Department = d, Instructor = i })
    .Select(x => new { x.Department, x.Instructor })
    .ToList();

//two trips
var inst = context.Instructors.Find(2)!;
context.Entry(inst).Reference<Department>(i => i.Dept).Load();
```

So in short I want a query that will be translated to this

```sql
select d.*, i.* 
from (
    select * from Instructor where Ins_Id=2
) as i
join  Department as d on i.Dept_Id = d.Dept_Id
```

is this possible or I should just do it in two trips, and if doing it in two trips is the only way which is better two trips or joining the whole tables?

Comment: First variant is the right way. What is wrong with that? Query will be similar to your SQL with the same performance. Don't think that database engine is dumb, it do a lot of things to optimise execution plan.

Comment: It's not the same when I see the profiler this is what it translates to:
[this](https://codeshare.io/yoXWWv)
and to my knowledge regarding the execution order in SQL that it joins then applies the where condition, so it joins the instructor and department tables fully then searches for the instructor with the given id.

Comment: As I know databases (20 years for now). This query is performant like yours. Database engine will put filter in correct order when processing query. Compare execution plans.